# Bound Image with converter not displaying in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, imagesource

I'm trying to make a window display some playing cards--simply a textblock with 'A'-'K' and a suit Image.  I have the images stored in Resources.resx as `Resources.Spades`, `Resources.Hearts`, etc.

In my Window.Resources xaml, I have

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Name="HighCardsResources">
    <c:SuitToImageConverter x:Key="SuitConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CardTemplate" DataType="{x:Type c:Card}">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" Width="50" Height="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RankText}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" />
                <Image Source="{Binding Suit, Converter={StaticResource SuitConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My `SuitToImageConverter` code is

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((Suit)value)
    {
        case Suit.Spades:
            return Resources.Spades;
        case Suit.Hearts:
            return Resources.Hearts;
        case Suit.Clubs:
            return Resources.Clubs;
        case Suit.Diamonds:
            return Resources.Diamonds;

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I'm dynamically adding `ContentPresenter`s to a grid.

```
int col = 0;
foreach (Card card in hand.Cards)
{
    DataTemplate template = FindResource("CardTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    ContentPresenter cp = new ContentPresenter();
    cp.ContentTemplate = template;
    cp.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
    cp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
    cp.Width = 50;
    cp.Height = 50;
    cp.Content = card;
    grdHand.Children.Add(cp);

    col++;
}
```

I know that the card is binding correctly because the TextBlock gets the correct string.  I also know that the `SuitToImageConverter` is being used, and that the correct image resource is being returned (via debugging).  For some reason, the image just isn't being displayed.  Ideas?

Comment: looks to me that Resources.* returns a collection and/or a resource set and not a single image!?

Comment: Are you saying that because of the 's' at the end of Spades and such?  Those were just the image names I used, and named so because you never say I have the Ace of Spade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this [link](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-images-from-project-resource.html).  Resx images are of type `Bitmap`, while `Image.Source` requires type `BitmapImage`.

I changed `SuitToImageConverter` to look like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    switch ((Suit)value)
    {
        case Suit.Spades:
            return ConvertToBitmapImage(Resources.Spades);
        case Suit.Hearts:
            return ConvertToBitmapImage(Resources.Hearts);
        case Suit.Clubs:
            return ConvertToBitmapImage(Resources.Clubs);
        case Suit.Diamonds:
            return ConvertToBitmapImage(Resources.Diamonds);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

private static BitmapImage ConvertToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    img.StreamSource = stream;
    img.EndInit();

    return img;
}
```

and now everything works.